# Odd javascript bug in safari, works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I am making a website, and I encountered an issue with variable definitions in Safari. The code runs fine in Chrome.

What I am trying to do is get the height of an element while it is truncated (using `-webkit-line-clamp`), so that I may animate the height to its full value later. What I am doing right now is setting the `-webkit-line-clamp` to unset (the initial value is 1), getting the height of the element, returning `-webkit-line-clamp` to 1, and then animating the `max-height`. The relevant code is as follows, with comments on the important lines.

```
$(".cd-timeline__block.js-cd-block").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(":last").children("h2").css("opacity", "1");
    var ele = $(this).children(":last").children(".content-wrapper-desc").children(":first");
    ele.css({"max-height": "max-content", "visibility": "hidden", "transition": "250ms", "-webkit-line-clamp": "unset", "opacity": "1"});
    var temp_height = ele.height();
    debugger; //in the debugger, ele.height() returns the correct value of the element's full height
    console.log(temp_height); //the console.log outputs the height of the truncated element
    ele.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'visibility': 'inherit',
        'max-height': '2rem',
        'display': '-webkit-box',
        'transition': '250ms !important',
       '-webkit-line-clamp': 'unset',
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(temp_height);
        ele.css("max-height", temp_height+"px"); //setTimeout with 1ms is to ensure that the animation runs. not entirely sure why this is necessary, but trial and error proved that it does.
    }, 1);

}, function(){
    $(this).children(":last").children("h2").css("opacity", "0.3");
    ele = $(this).children(":last").children(".content-wrapper-desc").children(":first");
    ele.css({"max-height": "2rem",  "-webkit-line-clamp": "unset", "opacity": "0.4"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        ele.css({"-webkit-line-clamp": "1"});
    }, 250);
});
```

---

### Here is what I see in the debugger

The code is here:

[image]

And when I go to the console and try to isolate the issue, this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: You've got the answer hiding in a comment! `setTimeout with 1ms is to ensure that the animation runs. not entirely sure why this is necessary, but trial and error proved that it does.`. Update the time from 1ms to `250ms` or whatever your transition time is. The transition is likely altering the results.

Comment: @Hodrobond I tried to change it to 1000ms, still doesn't work!

Comment: @Hodrobond also, that `setTimeout` is crucial to the animation working (in Chrome at least). Send me an email (on my profile) and I will send you the link to the actual website, but because my start-up is in stealth mode I can't put the link where it would be publicly visible.

Comment: Ohp, sorry, slightly misread placement of the `console.log`. Anyhow, if you're querying for height while it's changing...that's not really reliable.

Comment: You also have two transitions that fire before waiting for the other to finish? Do you need both? Do you need the height before or after transition?

Comment: Thing is, the `var temp_height = ele.height()` should run before the console.log or the `setTimeout` because it's not asynchronous.

Comment: If your first transition doesn't need a transition time, remove it. If it does need a transition time, wait for it to finish before querying height. If I ask a grade-schooler their height once a year, they'll give me a different answer every time I ask.

Comment: @Hodrobond that partially fixed yet, but it doesn't animate. At least it's the same cross-browser! Can you post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Have you tried `-webkit-transition` instead of/in addition to `transition` ?